# Add sorting to StackExchange Sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, sorting, stackexchange.com

Can we have custom sorting for [this page](https://stackexchange.com/sites)?

I'd like to see the sites ranked by the different columns available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done.  You can now sort the list using a dropdown at the top.

Comment: Would it be too much to ask for it to remember my last selection (at least when I'm logged in)? :)